# Node.js customize require function globally

Tags: node.js, module

I am trying to modify `require` like this

```
require = function (path) {
    try {
        return module.require(path);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(path)
    }
}
```

However, scope of this modification is only in the current module. I want to modify it globally, so every module that is `require`d by this module will also get the same copy of `require` function.

Basically, I want to catch `SyntaxError` to know which file has problem. I can't seem to find any other alternative. If I put `module.require` in `try/catch` block, I'll be able to get the file name which caused `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to solve it by modifying prototype function `require` of `Module` class. I put this in the main script and its available to all the `require`d modules.

```
var pathModule = require('path');
var assert = require('assert').ok;

module.constructor.prototype.require = function (path) {
    var self = this;
    assert(typeof path === 'string', 'path must be a string');
    assert(path, 'missing path');

    try {
        return self.constructor._load(path, self);
    } catch (err) {
        // if module not found, we have nothing to do, simply throw it back.
        if (err.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
            throw err;
        }
        // resolve the path to get absolute path
        path = pathModule.resolve(__dirname, path)

        // Write to log or whatever
        console.log('Error in file: ' + path);
    }
}
```

Comment: this seemed promising, but it did not work for me on Node 8. I put the modification in a mod.js and used Mocha's --require option to load it before all test files, but alas ...

Comment: As shown in [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireresolvepathsrequest) the nodejs spec includes functions `require.resolve(...)` and `require.resolve.paths(...)`.  Don't know if those get used internally or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a try-catch block inside your code and once an error occurs to check the stack trace. Check out these links

- [How to print a stack trace in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-nodejs)
- http://machadogj.com/2013/4/error-handling-in-nodejs.html

Comment: I can't use a try catch everywhere I require a module. and tell users to follow the same. That's why I want to make it transparent to the users.

Comment: What about http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception. You may put this in your main module and catch all those errors, which are normally send to the console.

Comment: `uncaughtException` is not much helpful when you want to catch `SyntaxError` as it won't give you the filename which has the error. Node just prints the filename with a snippet of the erroneous file. It doesn't give that file in the stacktrace.