# nodeStack.getFunctionName() returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following node.js code:

```
var path = require('path');
var nodeStack = require('stack-trace');
var controller = (function () {
    function controller() {
    }
    controller.prototype.render = function (res, model, view) {
        var stack = nodeStack.get();
        var frame = stack[1];
        var functionName = frame.getFunctionName().split(/controller\./i);
        if (functionName.length < 2) {
            functionName = frame.getFunctionName().split(/(controller|\./i);
        }
        if (!view) {
            view = functionName[1];
            var dotidx = view.indexOf('.');
            if (dotidx > -1) {
                view = view.substring(0, dotidx);
            }
        }
        if (!model) {
            model = {};
        }
        var base = '';
        if (res.locals.basePath) {
            base = res.locals.basePath;
        }
        var cls = functionName[0];
        res.render(path.join(base, cls, view), model);
    };
    return controller;
})();
module.exports = controller;
```

The code should allow me to render a view based on the method, the matching file should be found automatically.

It works all fine, just in one case `frame.getFunctionName()` returns null.

The code for the subclasses look as follows:

```
customerController.prototype.add = function (req, res) {
    var _this = this;
    somepromise.then(function (provider) {
        return provider.getCP();
    }).then(function (cp) {
        controller.prototype.render.call(_this, res, { title: 'add customer', contactpersons: cp });
    }, function (err) {
        controller.prototype.render.call(_this, res, { title: 'add customer' });
    });
};
```

The one code that doesn't work.

```
customerController.prototype.details = function (req, res) {
    var _this = this;
    somepromise.then(function (provider) {
        return provider.getCustomerById(req.param('id'));
    }).then(function (customer) {
        _super.prototype.render.call(_this, res, { title: 'customer details', customer: customer });
    }, function (err) {
        res.status(404).send(err);
    });
};
```

The code works for all methods except one. Do you have an idea why?

*Remarks: The code is compiled from TypeScript*

Comment: Maybe it is called from a closure? What do you see if you log the frame when getFunctionName returns null?

Comment: @Kenney they are all the same style like the one I posted. I will check the frame and add it.

Comment: @Kenney frame is always empty object

Comment: Ok, that was my first thought actually - the stack size is not at least 2 (though I would expect a 'attempt to invoke function on null object' or something). Or, is it not-null but empty? Maybe log the entire stack - it seems it is called from somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: @Kenney, I checked that and it resulted in all frames are empty object. So I am really lost by now :(

Comment: You say it works for all methods except one: can you update the question and add an example of either? Or is it all subclasses work except one? Might be a bug in the 'stack-trace' module; there are other ways: [traceback module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js), and [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) (i.e. `controller.prototype.render.caller.caller`). Other than that, I don't know..

Comment: One last thought - it could be called from 'top-level', perhaps via `setTimeout`. Since they are promise-based, you won't really know where they are called from, I would guess.

Comment: @Kenney I added the code. your idea with the promises I like, I will dig into that.

Comment: @Kenney, I just checked in Visual Studio, there I get the full callstack and that includes the correct informations.