# Nodejs how to send the full error object to frontend

Tags: node.js

I need to send a error message, and the full error object from nodejs backend to frontend.

I issue a error not declaring "ret" variable.

In my frontend I receive:

```
{"success":false,"message":"ret is not defined","results":{}}
```

As we can see, the results is empty. How could I receive the full "err" object into "results"?

//error log-backend

```
ReferenceError: ret is not defined
    at router.get (C:\nodeapp\cloudnh_v2\server\routes\config_geral.js:24:8)
    at <anonymous>
```

//router

```
'use strict';
    router.get('/',async (req,res,next)=>{  
        try {
           const connection = await pool.getConnection();
           try {
              ret={success:true}
              return res.send(ret);
            } finally {
                pool.releaseConnection(connection);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return  res.status(500).send({ success:false,message: err.message, results:err}); // 500
      }
    });
```

Comment: i guess you need to throw err first to catch it later or you can use promises

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a stack trace in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js)

Comment: @TGrif Yes, I know. I am simulating an error and I´d like to see that error on frontend.

Comment: @str I don´t think my question is a duplicate. My problem is send the error object to frontend not print the stack on backend.

Comment: @LuizAlves You already seem to know how to send information from the backend to the frontend (you are sending `err.message`, for example). So your question isn't really about the sending part but about the accessing part. The linked question answers exactly that (`err.stack`).

Comment: @str Ok, thank you. (err.stack) solved my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
'use strict';
router.get('/',async (req,res,next)=>{  
    try {
       const connection = await pool.getConnection();
       try {
          ret={success:true}
          return res.send(ret);
        } finally {
            pool.releaseConnection(connection);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return  res.status(500).json({ success:false,message: err.message, results:JSON.stringify(err)}); // 500
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but It doesn´t works. I have the same empty results

Comment: check whether you are getting err inside catch by console.log(err) or not .I think There is problem in inner try

Comment: in my question I put the log of backend. To print it, I used console.log(err) into catch block.