# Replicate normal NodeJS error printing behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

When node encounters an caught exception, it prints the line the error occurred on, followed by the stack trace, then exits:

```
/example.js:1
throw new Error()
^

Error
    at ...
```

I would like to catch an exception, print exactly the same thing, and continue. Basically:

```js
try {
  something();
} catch (e) {
  // what goes here?
  console.error(e);
}
```

Note that the above example already prints the stack trace. The missing part is the first four lines, including the file/line reference, line text, and column indicator.

Comment: `console.error(e)`?

Comment: Are you asking how to replicate the printed node errors?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js

Comment: @ajmeese7 Yes, that is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That question asks how to print a stack trace. The example code in this question already prints a stack trace; the missing part is `// what goes here?`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) property of Error:

```
try {
  something();
} catch (e) {
  console.err(e.stack);
}
```

Comment: This is functionally almost identical to the example code in the question. It does not print the entire specified output (what node prints for uncaught exceptions).