# how to access same functionality as console.log(Error('example')) without console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js

example:

```
> console.log(Error('test'))
Error: test
    at repl:1:13
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:20)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:404:29)
    at bound (domain.js:420:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:433:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:715:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:316:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:693:8)
```

I want to store this entire string with stack as a string. But this doesn't work, it doesn't have the stack. How can I access the same functionality?

```
> e = Error('test')
> console.log(e.toString())
Error: test
> console.log('' + e)
Error: test
```

Comment: e.stack is the stack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a stack trace in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the `stack` property of the error instance:

```js
const foo = () => {
  bar();
};
const bar = () => {
  const error = new Error('some error');
  console.log(error.stack);
};

foo();
```