# AWS Lambda Node error logging: Is it necessary to separately log the stack?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging

Some of the example code in the AWS Javascript SDK docs log the stack of an error separately to the error itself, for example this is from the [`AWS.CloudWatch` overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html):

```
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
cloudwatch.getMetricWidgetImage(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

So far as I can tell, this is redundant in Node (I have only tested on v10.16). If I log just the error object, it includes the stack trace:

```
> console.log(e)
Error: x
    at repl:2:8
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:332:29)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:415:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:642:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:308:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:451:12)
undefined
```

Whereas if I log both, as Amazon have done above, I get an ugly ouput with duplication:

```
> console.log(e, e.stack)
Error: x
    at repl:2:8
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:332:29)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:415:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:642:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:308:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:451:12) 'Error: x\n    at repl:2:8\n    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)\n    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:332:29)\n    at bound (domain.js:402:14)\n    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:415:12)\n    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:642:10)\n    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:198:13)\n    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)\n    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:308:10)\n    at REPLServer.Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:451:12)'
undefined
```

Is there some reason that Amazon are using the `console.log(err, err.stack)` pattern that I am missing if I just do `console.log(err)`?

(I am primarily using Node in an AWS Lambda, version 10.x)

Comment: Possibly a carryover from older Node.js behavior, mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593443/1695906

Comment: Thanks @Michael - sqlbot, yes, that explains it: it was required for Node < 6. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log(err, err.stack)` formula was required for Node versions < 6, as they did not log the error stack by default.

More recent Node versions can just do `console.log(err)`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593443/1695906 for a bit more detail

(The oldest Node offered by AWS Lambda at the time of writing is Node.js 8.10, so perhaps AWS should update their docs now to remove this.)

(From "@Michael - sqlbot"'s comment, thanks!)