# Nodejs permanent stack tracing to file

Tags: node.js, process, stack, trace

`console.trace("Here I am!")` - prints stack trace in current position of code. Is it possible to start writing stack trace from the beginning of script (or certain position) till the end of script to external log file like (`/tmp/myTraceFile_${process.pid}`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593443/1519836 answers your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a stack trace in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js)

Comment: I need permanent log writing, not by manual calling