# How to fix cloudinary error "Must supply api_key"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer, cloudinary

I'm building an image upload app using multer and cloudinary. I've configured my environment variables properly using dotenv. However, when I try to upload files using Cloudinary I get the error "Must supply api_key".

The Cloudinary API credentials are correctly supplied and provisioned as in the code below:

**cloudinary.js**

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
})

exports.uploads = (file, folder) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, (result) => {
            resolve({
                url: result.url,
                id: result.public_id
            })
        }, {
            resource_type: "auto",
            folder: folder
        })
    })
}
```

**.env**

```
CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME='my_cloudinary_cloud_name'
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY='my_cloudinary_api_key'
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET='my_cloudinary_api_secret'
```

The .env file is also required correctly in my app.js file:

**app.js**

```
require('dotenv').config({
    path: './app/config/.env'
});
```

If I console.log any of the cloudinary config variables inside the cloudinary.js file, I get the expected output, but when I try to use cloudinary in my upload route, I get the error that I must supply api_key. Please can someone help me point out what I'm doing wrong? I don't want to have to write out my cloudinary config variables in the cloudinary.js file because the code is being published to Github.

Here is my post route using cloudinary:

```
const express = require('express'),
    Product = require('../app/models/product'),
    upload = require('../app/utils/multer'),
    cloudinary = require('../app/utils/cloudinary'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    router = express.Router();

router.post('/products', upload.array('image'), async (req, res) => {
    const uploader = async (path) => await cloudinary.uploads(path, 'Images');
    const urls = []
    const files = req.files
    for (const file of files) {
        const {
            path
        } = file;
        const newPath = await uploader(path)
        urls.push(newPath)
        fs.unlinkSync(path)
    }

    const name = req.body.name

    const product = new Product({
        name: name,
        imageone: urls[0].url,
        imagetwo: urls[1].url,
        imagethree: urls[2].url,
        imagefour: urls[3].url
    })

    product.save(function (err, prod) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            req.flash('success', "You have added a new product.")
            res.redirect("/dashboard")
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kóyo @awesome-bassey!

Following cloudinary [docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#installation_and_setup) for Nodejs and it's official [repo](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm) i would advice you to import `v2` of the cloudinary API.

*In case your issue still remains - please share stack-trace with us*

Comment: I have imported v2. It still didn't work. I've also tried a lot of other options too... Please how can I share stack-trace?

Comment: here you can read some more about [stack-trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js)

and of course I'd suggest to double check that your `.env` is getting loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Node.js v2, it can be declared as shown in the following code sample as described in the [installation setup document](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#installation_and_setup) (i.e. *require('cloudinary')**.v2***):

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2; 

cloudinary.config({ 
   cloud_name: '<YOUR_CLOUD_NAME>', 
   api_key: '<YOUR_API_KEY>', 
   api_secret: '<YOUR_API_SECRET>',
   secure: true
});

cloudinary.uploader.upload("my_image.jpg", 
          function(error, result) {
             console.log(result, error);
});
```