# Get the caller's directory root from a node.js package

Tags: javascript

Imagine a directory structure like this:

```
module
  index.js

project
  main.js
  file.yaml
```

Imagine further that inside the `module/index.js` file, there is this code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

exports.test = function() {
  // How should I *dynamically* reference the caller's app root directory?
  console.log(fs.readFileSync('file.yaml', 'utf8'));
}
```

Inside the `project/main.js` file, there is this code:

```js
const x = require('./module');

x.test();
```

And inside the `project/file.yaml` file, there is this code:

```yaml
foo: bar
```

I want `x.test();` to output the contents of `project/file.yaml`, somehow *dynamically* referencing the caller's root directory.

Comment: `__dirname` is the tool at your disposal.  You can also try harvesting the path out of a [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923858/how-to-print-a-stack-trace-in-node-js).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? `__dirname` gives the root dir of this file. So, no matter where this function gets called it will have correct location of `file.yaml`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

exports.test = function(fileLocation) {
  // How should I *dynamically* reference the caller's app root directory?
  console.log(fs.readFileSync(fileLocation), 'utf8'));
}
```

```js
// Calling location
test(path.join(__dirname, './file.yaml')
```

Comment: Not exactly. I need `file.yaml` to be able to change location and still work, as this will become a npm package.

Comment: hmm i don't think you can do that. 
But in packages you can pass the location of your file as a argument to your test function and read it from there. I have updated my answer